# How can I command Outlook to ask, every time that I email, to specify from which account the email should be sent?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My grandfather has on his laptop Outlook 2016, which contains both his and my grandmother's 2 separate Outlook accounts.

But whenever he emails on behalf of my grandfather, often my grandfather forgets to change the 'From:' field, indicated by the red arrows:
[image]

So to resolve his forgetfulness, he wishes Outlook to force him to choose which email account from which to send an outgoing email, every time he does so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: goto File > Options > Mail, then uncheck "Always use default account when composing new messages"